# PHP - How to keep the UTF-8 encoding without using the header ("Content-Type:.......?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, header

If at the beginning of my PHP script I use the line:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8",true);
```

I can not redirect pages:

```
header("Location: index.php")
```

so how do I set the encoding is UTF-8 and you still can use this redirect code?

Can you use redirection with a Javascript line, but do not think getting correct closing and opening the php to insert Javascript.

Comment: Can you not use a meta equivalent for `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` in `<head></head>`? `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Comment: ^This is maybe your solution, but for me i can write the 2 lines and it works

Comment: Can I use so early in the .....<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></h......  on pages that have ONLY SCRIPT PHP?

Comment: Sure you can. Try 'er out. Just make sure your header is first. Then again, it may not make a difference.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/27952017/2777820 !

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the content-type of the document shouldn't prevent an HTTP redirect from working… but most users won't see the document anyway. It is only there for clients that don't automatically follow the HTTP redirect.

For most clients, they will be redirected to `index.php` (note that there is an error in your Location header, the HTTP specification requires that is holds an *absolute* URI, not a relative one) and then `index.php` will be responsible for describing the content type of the document it outputting.

You need to put `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8",true)` in `index.php` and not in the script that redirects to it.